# Drupal apply patch

Tags: drupal, patch, putty

I try to apple patch to the module using Putty
`patch -p1 change_frequency_option-1811692-35.patch`
but I got error `-bash: patch: command not found`.
How to apply patch in this case?

**UPD**
I didn't have an opportunity to use command `patch -p1 < change_frequency_option-1811692-35.patch` on the server, so I tried to apply patch using git
 `git apply -v --directory=sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap change_frequency_option-1811692-35.patch` but in this case I got errors

$ git apply -v --directory=sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap change_frequency_option-1811692-35.patch
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.admin.inc...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.generate.inc...
error: while searching for:
  if ($save_custom) {
    $query->condition('status_override', 0);
    $query->condition('priority_override', 0);
  }

return $query->execute();

error: patch failed: sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.generate.inc:545
error: sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.generate.inc: patch does not apply
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.install...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.js...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap.module...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap_menu/xmlsitemap_menu.module...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap_node/xmlsitemap_node.module...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap_node/xmlsitemap_node.test...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap_taxonomy/xmlsitemap_taxonomy.module...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap_user/xmlsitemap_user.module...
Checking patch sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap/xmlsitemap_user/xmlsitemap_user.test...

What's wrong? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing patch command. If it's ubuntu something like:

```
sudo apt-get install patch
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it should work, but unfortunately I don't have the enough rights to use this command on the server, so I will try other solutions. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use
git apply -v path/file.patch

See https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply for details

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work (I added update to the question)

Comment: "patch does not apply" means the patch doesn't suit your module version. Maybe you need the latest dev version or trying to use an old patch file that is already commited to module.

Comment: Nope, I downloaded the site on my local computer and applied patch using command `patch -p1 < change_frequency_option-1811692-35.patch` and all worked just fine and patch was applied. But command `git apply -v --directory=sites/all/modules/xmlsitemap change_frequency_option-1811692-35.patch` if I try to use it locally doesn't work with the same errors.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/change_frequency_option-1811692-35.patch    the issue post here https://www.drupal.org/node/1811692#comment-11098173

Comment: try to download and apply this patch in the same directory where the xmlsitemap.generate.inc file is located

Comment: git apply -v change_frequency_option-1811692-35.patch

Comment: I applied patch but now I have a problem with sitemap generation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716993/drupal-error-after-applying-xmlsitemap-module-patch