# Drupal error after applying xmlsitemap module patch

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I use xmlsitemap module and I need to change frequency option, so I tried to apply the patch https://www.drupal.org/node/1811692, the patch was applied successfully, but in this case after I got an error with sitemap generation, when I try rebuild sitemap
[image]
[image]

What's wrong? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Try to look at Recent log messages to track the error

Comment: I checked, there are no errors about the problem or the module in log.

Comment: You can also open Firebug's (or similar) Network tab before running Batch process to see Request/Responce details. Don't forget to check php error log